# Select dropdownlist value from session

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dropdown list in my html file.

I want the location (in the dropdown) to be automatically selected if it is present in the session object if session.

I hope you understand my question. I am new to mvc. Thanks

```
@if (Session["Location"] == null)
{
                <select class="form-control" id="DeliveryLocation" name="DeliveryLocation">
                    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Your Location</option>
                    <option value="Aundh">Aundh</option>
                    <option value="Baner">Baner</option>
                    <option value="Balewadi">Balewadi</option>
                    <option value="Pimpri">Pimpri</option>
                    <option value="Nilakh">Nilakh</option>
                    <option value="Wakad">Wakad</option>

                </select>
}
else
{
    // i want code here to select value from dropdown as it is in location session
   <pre> <select class="form-control" id="DeliveryLocation" name="DeliveryLocation">
                    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Your Location</option>
                    <option value="Aundh">Aundh</option>
                    <option value="Baner">Baner</option>
                    <option value="Balewadi">Balewadi</option>
                    <option value="Pimpri">Pimpri</option>
                    <option value="Nilakh">Nilakh</option>
                    <option value="Wakad">Wakad</option>

                </select>
}
```

Comment: You could add javascript further down such as document.getElementById('DeliveryLocation').value = '@Session["Location"]';

Answer (score 0):

100% work in your situation.

```
<select class="form-control" id="DeliveryLocation" name="DeliveryLocation">
    <option @(Session["location"] == null ? "selected disabled hidden": "")>Choose location</option>
    <option @((string)Session["location"] == "USA" ? "selected" : "")>USA</option>
    <option @((string)Session["location"] == "Praga" ? "selected" : "")>Praga</option>
    <option @((string)Session["location"] == "Paris" ? "selected" : "")>Paris</option>
    <option @((string)Session["location"] == "China" ? "selected" : "")>China</option>
    <option @((string)Session["location"]== "GB" ? "selected":"")>GB</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your code belongs in the `else` branch -- the `if` is checking whether it is null.

Comment: bro not working... is something wrong in below line :

Comment: <option @(sessionVal.Equals("Aundh"))? "selected":"") value="Aundh">Aundh</option>

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SelectList` and MVC's `HTML Helpers` to build your dropdown. It looks daunting if you're new to `MVC`, but it simplifies a lot of stuff for you.

In your current action method that loads this page:

```
ViewBag.DeliveryLocation = new SelectList(new[]
{
    new { Text = "Aundh", Value = "Aundh" },
    new { Text = "Balewadi", Value = "Balewadi" },
    new { Text = "Pimpri", Value = "Pimpri" }
}, "Value", "Text", Session["Location"]);
```

There are a bunch of overloads for the `SelectList` class. So the above code creates a `SelectList` with the collection where `Value` property will be bound to option's `value` attribute and `Text` will be displayed as the `option`'s text. The next parameter is `selectedValue`. In your case, you'd want to set to whatever is there in the `Session["Location"]`.

You can also create a list of `SelectListItem` and put it in a `ViewBag`.

And then in your view,

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeliveryLocation")
```

That's it. So what happens here is, Razor generates a `<select>` element with `name="DeliveryLocation"`. Then it looks for a `DeliveryLocation` property in the `ViewBag`. WE have set this in our controller and the options will be set accordingly.

Let's say, you have set `ViewBag.DeliveryLocationList` in your controller with the `SelectList`. Then you'd have to tell razor where to look for a `SelectList`. And since `ViewBag` is a dynamic object, you'd have to cast it.

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeliveryLocation", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DeliveryLocationList,  "Choose Your Location", new { @id= "DeliveryLocation" })
```

Here you have hardcoded the locations. In real applications, the option values like Locations will usually be fetched from the database. Then you don't have to make big changes if you use HTML helpers.

[This link from Microsft docs has some great examples for beginners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)